# pre-authorize a credit card using PayPal

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

My application must ensure that the customer has enough credit available, but without actually debiting the customer's account until the order is delivered. After delivery of order, the amount should then be charged.

Comment: Why would you want to do this. It's a risk, because there may not be enough credit available by the time you try to charge.

Comment: Can't i hold that **pre-autorize** amount, so that later it would be charged from account???

Comment: What is the difference between claiming it an already charging it? In both cases, the customer can't use the money.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely; see [Using Authorization & Capture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PayPal by authorizing the user and if the user is authorized then you can send them for payment. You can also reserve the fund and process it when date occurs. You can find more in the following link.

**PayPal Payments Pro**
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro

**Express Checkout**
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted